# java coding problem: hangs on a arraylist add

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

i used before arraylist as structure  but in this piece of code it doesnt works.
Can someone help me  since i cant find the error ? (i am sure it s  my mistake but the IDE says nothing)

the flow:
first the class Game. i call the runGame  adn it flows ok untill the point **Hand hand = new Hand(this.deck);**   ( ther is a comment on the right to signale the problem

```
public class Game {

        private ArrayList<Player> playerArray;
    private int maxPlayers;
        private Deck deck;

    //constructor
    public Game(ArrayList playerArray, int maxPlayers)
    {
        this.playerArray = playerArray;
        this.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
        }

    // game method for the match
    public  void runGame()
        {
            //shuffle of players
            Collections.shuffle(this.playerArray);

            //creation of the deck
            this.deck = new Deck();
            System.out.println(new java.util.Date().toString() +"  "+"deck created");

            //shuffle the deck 
            this.deck.shuffleDeck();
            System.out.println(new java.util.Date().toString() +"  "+"deck shuffled");


            // distribuiting the hands to all players
            //and preventing them to send something
            for (int i = 0; i < this.maxPlayers; i++)
            {
                Player currentPlayer = this.playerArray.get(i);
                Socket socket = currentPlayer.getConnection();

                Hand hand = new Hand(this.deck);// the problem starts here  comes form the constructor of the hand
                 System.out.println(" after hand ");

                sendingBlockString(socket, currentPlayer); //send the block string
                sendingHand(socket, currentPlayer, hand );//send the hand
            }
```

The problem is clearly in the hand constructor in the class Hand      where it hangs in the  cycle   for, exaclty trying  to add the popped car of the deck ( the deck.popCard() function is tested and works perfectly so it s not that blocking the add() function  )   i never reach the second system.out.println     here the code:

```
public class Hand  implements Serializable
{

    private ArrayList<Card> theHand;
    private Player player;
    private int handValue ;  // from 1  to 10 


        public Hand(Deck deck)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
            { 
                System.out.println("before popping deck");
                this.theHand.add(i, deck.popCard());// adding the card taken from the deck (5 times)  //// this is the problem  it hangs!
                System.out.println("after add to hand");
            }

         }
```

Comment: Is `theHand` field initialized somewhere? If it is not then calling `this.theHand.add` will cause a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Where is theHand initialized? You don't get a NullPointerException, so you must omitting code that is initializing theHand. Also, are you sure that deck.popCard() is not guilty? Better you would post that method too.

Comment: thx  Dunaril was right  it was nullpointerexception   so i have to initialize it....  sorry  people... i ma very new to java  i ll never do this error again!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it hangs ? It should throw a NullPointerException since your ArrayList is not initialized.

Comment: yes !!  u area genius  but how to initialize the array since  i have to create  fill it in that moment ???

Comment: It is really a basic error as suggested by all your question's comments. Just add a line "theHand = new ArrayList<Card>();" at the first line of your constructor. One question though: this kind of error throws an error, it does not make it hang... Or maybe you were running this code flow in a separate thread ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that `dec.popCard()` blocks if there are no more cards. the `add` method itself can't hang.

Comment: but the deck is full and i tested it,   doing deck.popCard() before the this.hand.add() and assigned to an object card that i pass to the add method .....mhhh  i ll check further   thx!!